# How to Move to next record while building an IEnumerable if the current row has data problems

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that outputs a list of RSVPs for a class. The RSVP is based on a pull from a SQL table holding RSVP records, based on an input parameter of the class id. Then a dictionary of all students (people who RSVPd to that class) is made. Finally I output the IEnumerable of the RSVPs based on the data for each student.

The problem I'm running into is that I've got a couple students in the data that are "bad users": They aren't in the system. Potentially because of bad record deletions, or bad creations. Either way, I need to set up error handling for "bad student records" while building the IEnumerable.

My thought was to catch the potential error when evaluating the student id on this line:

```
var data = x.ToRsvpData(students[x.RawAgentId]);
```

And then just skip that record and move on to the next one. However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Here's the complete method:

```
public IEnumerable<RsvpData> GetAllRsvpsFor(Guid scheduledId)
    {
        var rsvps = _sors.AnyRsvpsIn(new[] { scheduledId })[scheduledId];
        var certificates = _sors.CertificatesIn(rsvps.Select(x => x.RsvpId).ToList());

        var students = _sors.StudentsBy(rsvps);
        return rsvps.Select(x => {
            var data = x.ToRsvpData(students[x.RawAgentId]);
            if (x.Completed) 
            {
                data.SignatureUrl = StaticContent.S3WebPrefixFor(string.Format("/schools/signatures/{0}.jpg", x.RsvpId.ToString()));
                var cert = certificates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Rsvp.RsvpId == x.RsvpId);
                data.CertificateId = cert != null ? cert.CertId.ToString() : "";
            }
            return data;
        }).OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ToList();
    }
```

---

***Update***: 
Here's the completed, working code:

```
public IEnumerable<RsvpData> GetAllRsvpsFor(Guid scheduledId)
{
    var rsvps = _sors.AnyRsvpsIn(new[] { scheduledId })[scheduledId];
    var certificates = _sors.CertificatesIn(rsvps.Select(x => x.RsvpId).ToList());

    var students = _sors.StudentsBy(rsvps);

    var cleanRsvpData = new List<RsvpData>();
    foreach (var rsvp in rsvps)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = rsvp.ToRsvpData(students[rsvp.RawAgentId]);
            if (rsvp.Completed)
            {
                data.SignatureUrl = StaticContent.S3WebPrefixFor(string.Format("/schools/signatures/{0}.jpg", rsvp.RsvpId.ToString()));
                var cert = certificates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Rsvp.RsvpId == rsvp.RsvpId);
                data.CertificateId = cert != null ? cert.CertId.ToString() : "";
            }
            cleanRsvpData.Add(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { //Bad Student record
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using lambda expressions, your best bet would probably be to use a temp list variable and use a try catch block - so only the "clean" records will make it into your list:

```
List<RsvpData> cleanRsvpData = new List<RsvpData>();
        foreach (RsvpData rsvp in rsvps)
        {
            try
            {
                RsvpData data = rsvp.ToRsvpData(students[x.RawAgentId]);
                if (rsvp.Completed)
                {
                    data.SignatureUrl = "test";
                    var cert = certificates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Rsvp.RsvpId == x.RsvpId);
                    data.CertificateId = cert != null ? cert.CertId.ToString() : "";
                }
                cleanRsvpData.Add(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { // handle error here
            }
        }
```

Since the try catch is INSIDE the loop, it won't break your whole loop if one of the items in the list throws an error.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Posting the full 'fix' in my notes above. Thank you!

Comment: this is the worst possible solution... both performance wise, and because your data is broken.

Comment: It actually handles the broken data rather well. I went in and broke the data purposefully after putting this into play to see how it handles it. The result: beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what makes them particularly misbehaving records, simply wrapping your `Enumerable` in another `Enumerable` should fix the problem. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Record> GetCorrectRecords(IEnumerable<Record> records)
{
   foreach(var record in records)
     if(record.Valid)               // up to you how you define this
       yield return record;
}
```

Comment: In this instance, the problem is that `students[x.RawAgentId]` is failing because the "x.RawAgentId" isn't a member of Students. (This is what I meant by 'bad users' - the student id is somehow attached the RSVP record, but there's no matching student/user information for that user.

I fixed this issue by updating the database for those users, but I'm trying to prevent future issues. The problem that occurs is that if `students[x.RawAgentId]` throws an error, the whole IEnumerable fails to get built. Ideally, I'd just like to skip over those 'bad' records, and move on to the next one.

Comment: So make that your condition, `if(students.Contains(x.RawAgentId)) yield return ...students[x.RawAgentId]...;` ideally with some memoization.

Comment: @PKD you should probably adjust your mapping to handle this, or setup foreign keys in the DB

Comment: The FK's are in the DB - I tracked the bad users down thanks to figuring out that someone temporarily deleted the FK to import new records. It's been causing issues, but this should help nip it in the bud.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the famous try...catch block, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetAllRsvpsFor(Guid scheduledId)
    {
        //all the code that precedes the loop
        //for or foreach loop
        {
            //any code that you have to perform after this block
            try
            {
                var data = x.ToRsvpData(students[x.RawAgentId]);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue; //continues to the next for iteration in case of any error
            }
            //any code that you have to perform after this block
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the idea I was looking for, but the problem with a continue is that a lambda expression cannot contain a continue statement whose target is outside the body or in the body of a contained anonymous function. Since the building of the rsvps is a lambda statement, the continue just throws a nasty "Unresolved Jump" error.